# Custom Login and Register Trouble

Tags: php, wordpress

Am creating a custom login and register pages for WordPress, so using `wp_insert_user()` to create the new user on the registration page and on login page I used `wp_signon()` to validate the user with password.

After I created the new user, I can’t able to log-in using wp_signon, always throw an error `“ERROR:` The password you entered for the email address `xxx@xxx.com` is incorrect. Lost your password?”

If I manually reset the password from Admin dashboard under profile setting for `xxx@xx.com` then I can able to log-in using `wp_signon()` function.

Though I have var_dump the result on wp_include/user.php on wp_authenticate_email_password() and wp_authenticate_username_password(). Its show the exact details as in DB for all users `$password, $user->user_pass`, `$user->ID`.

`wp_check_password()` is return false for newly created user by `wp_insert_user()` and true for the same user after manually reset password in admin dashboard.

I don’t know where the problem is. Please suggest me the solution.

Thanks

Comment: sign up with a password, save the hash from the db, go to the dashboard and reset the password with the same password. check the db for the password with the previously saved one and see if they are different. if so, you are doing something or not doing something to the password to save it correctly

Comment: @khuderm: Yes I even tried like that in Admin dashboard by reset the same password and check the user_pass column in user table. But all time it shows different, but its working. The problem is whenever I tried to reset the password from Admin Dashboard its keep on changing and working. But when I tried to add the user with wp_insert_user() then I can't able to login.

Comment: if the passwords are showing different, there is something wrong with your code. you will have to post it here in order to get help. otherwise, it is just guesses. plus you will get more people to help out if you have code

Comment: Am sorry! I found the solution, actually I have wrongly passed the password name field as user_password instead of user_pass.